# How to handle exact UITouch of image?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, touch

I have an image for example triangle and place it inside UIImageView, and I have a touch and drag application, I can already drag the triangle but my problem is I can still drag the triangle even if I'm not actually touching the triangle, (Im touching the upper left of the triangle image) I think this is because the UIImageView itself is a square so although I have not touch the triangle image but I have touch the square UIImageView that's why I can still drag it w/o touching the triangle,

So the question would be how can I make this accurate, like I can only drag it if I have touch the triangle image and not really the square ImageView?

Hopeful for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UIButton, try using [CGPath](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html) and testing for CGPathContainsPoint.

Also, try [LaMarche's Improved Irregular UIButton](http://www.iphone4gnew.com/improved-irregular-shape-uibutton.html).

Otherwise, you could use some trigonometry to determine where the touch occurred and whether or not it is within your internal shape.